# Objective C touch event locking

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

Currently I'm running into an issue where there are table cells that allow for touch events to get there details. However, if the user presses the cell 2-4 times within 1 second it causes multiple view pushes onto the navigation view controller. This causes obvious errors when the views are popped off and the navigation controller has trouble going to a sub view and coming back. Leading to multiple traps, most unfortunately don't come with a error log. However, since this behavior shouldn't be supported in the first place. The question is besides thread locking is there other ways to prevent multiple touch events on either UiButtons or on table cells?

--Side Info--
Side information you may want, I am working with Xcode Version 6.4 due to the https vs http security settings added in Xcode 7. If later versions of Xcode automatically implement solutions to this then that would be good to know as well. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Show your code that happens from the touch.

Comment: I'll post some here in a minute.

Comment: You are doing too much work before viewDidAppear in the next (pushed) UIViewController which in turn blocks the UI thread. This cause receiving UITouchEvent while you expect to enter transition action to the new UIViewController. I don not recommend using the userinteraction enable flag.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be helped to much of the data displayed isn't static. It is highly dynamic and shares many common properties with other Views elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lock a button (or cell) after it tapped:

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

or whole interface:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

and unlock when transition/loading is done.

Comment: That seems like it will work, ill give it a test and see.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to throttle the touch events with GCD, both `UIButton` and `UIGestureRecognizer` exposes an `enabled` property.  You can simply disable the button after one touch, and re-enable it after you've pushed the detail view controller.

An easy way to re-enable it would be in the `viewWillAppear` method of the controller pushing the detail view--that way the `enabled` property would be automatically reset whenever you went back to that view controller without having to listen to `UINavigationController` transitions, etc.